# testing multiple classes using test suit on junit5 gets pending

Tags: java, testing, junit, junit5

I've written multiple test classes to test my methods using junit 5. 
all the test classes pass successfully when I run them indivually
but when I try to run them all at a time using a test suite as shown below, some of my tests get pending and the testing won't finish. it doesn't even jump to test other classes

[image]
as all the methods pass successfully, I don't think if there's any problem with  the class ParametrizedMethodTest

I'm using junit-platform-runner version 1-6-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the current [JavaDoc](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.runner/org/junit/platform/runner/JUnitPlatform.html):

> Please note that test classes and suites annotated with
>   @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class) cannot be executed directly on the JUnit
>   Platform (or as a "JUnit 5" test as documented in some IDEs). Such
>   classes and suites can only be executed using JUnit 4 infrastructure.

In other words, JUnit 5 does not support test suites in the way you want to do it in your example. If you want to run all your tests classes just select the package and choose Run Tests from the context menu.